# iOS UIWebView Event when opening new window

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ios7, ios6

I try to create an iOS application that display a webview but the website I want to display open sometime a new window. ( window.open ) I had no problem on other device to add a listener and do something when the application is trying to open a new window but on iOS I have no idea how to create this type of listener.
Is there a way to add a listener and do something when the app try to open a new window ?
For the moment, when I click on a link with a window.open, the app open a new webview on top and there is no way to go back to the old view.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIApplication*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    NSString *url = request.URL.absoluteString;
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && [url rangeOfString:@"........].location==NSNotFound){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        NSLog(@"opening link on default browser");
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is determine whether the URL will be opened externally or not.

You can do this using the following:

```
- (BOOL)isExternal:(NSURL*)url {
    BOOL isExternal = NO;
    if (![url.scheme isEqual:@"http"] && ![url.scheme isEqual:@"https"]) {
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
            isExternal = YES;
        }
    }
    return isExternal;
}
```

Then from the `UIWebViewDelegate`, use this method to decide wether or not to allow loading of the URL:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIApplication*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    BOOL allowToLoad = ([self isExternal:request.URL] == NO);
    return allowToLoad;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this on my code and it seems not to work. My application still open a new window for some links and isExternal return 1. The url.scheme is a https

Answer (score 0):

Please, see [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad%3a) and its method webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: and webViewDidFinishLoad:.

Comment: Yes that is what i have done. But I don't know how to add a delegate to check if the application will open a new window

Comment: have you tried this : http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/09/14/making-target-_blank-links-work-in-a-uiwebview/ ?

Comment: Actually I think it is not the same problem. I made a mistake in my explanation. I thought it was a target blank but it is a javascript code window.open